# Rack-Flash sinatra issues

Tags: ruby, rack

I've got a small sinatra app that I'm using rack-flash for a 'not logged in' alert. The setup is quite simple, checking for a session and returning an error message in no session is found.

I've been finding the whole thing quite temperamental though. the flashes show on my local server but not at all on my remote. I've been through the code, and examples numerous times and can't seem to find a bug. The route and template are below:

```
get '/item/new' do
  if session?
    erb :new_item
  else
    flash[:error] = 'not logged in'
    redirect '/'
  end
end
```

and view is

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
  <div id="flash-message">
    <%= flash[:error] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have rack-flash and sessions set up as such:

```
use Rack::Flash, :sweep => true
use Rack::Session::Cookie
```

any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [sinatra-flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash)? I haven't really tried rack-flash but sinatra-flash has always worked for me.

Comment: I did have a look at it, but am reluctant to add another module just for flashes. Might end up trying it if I can't work this out. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve a value from the flash, it erases it. So when you do "if flash[:error]" you are perhaps retrieving it? Use has? to check if something is there.

Comment: HI Tom, thanks for the feedback. I ended up going with sinatra-flash due to the styling option, wich is all working well.

Answer (score 1):

Since `<FlashHash @values={} @cache={}>` from `rack-flash` is basically a Hash you can just use `#has?` to check whether a key/message is present. Checkout the example:

```
  <% if flash.has?(:notice) %>
    <div class="alert alert-block">
      <%= flash[:notice] %> 
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I know this comes a bit late, but i hope it helps.

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack-flash/0.1.2/Rack/Flash/FlashHash#has%3F-instance_method